# HTTPS connection is showing an unsecure sign though certificate was configured

Tags: security, ssl, https

I have created a certificate with:

```
sudo openssl req $@ -new -x509 -days 730 -nodes -out /etc/nginx/cert.pem -keyout /etc/nginx/cert.key
```

but on my [**website**](https://www.ljtd.eu/) it shows that it's not save to use. How is the right command for getting a save connection? What did I forget?

[image]

Also the Server config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.ljtd.eu ljtd.eu;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.ljtd.eu ljtd.eu;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

        location / { 
            if (!-e $request_filename)
                {
                rewrite ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
                rewrite ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?(/.*\.php)$ $2 last;
                rewrite ^ /index.php last;
                }
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using a self signed certificated, it will never be assumed safe unless you install it to the local root certification store. (but this will work for you only, not for others). Either life with it or pay for a real certificate.

Comment: Or using this one right? https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: @kwoxer LE is indeed a free certificate authority, but it's still in beta and there are some know issues, limitations and rate-limits. You should definitely look into it, but don't assume it will magically fit your needs just because it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a [self signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate), therefore the connection will be encrypted but it's untrusted (as it was signed by you and not by a publicly trusted certificate authority).

To get a trusted certificate, you'll need to purchase one from a certification authority or a reseller. Prices vary from few dollars to hundreds of dollars, depending on the type of certificate, coverage and the names.

Some CAs also offer a domain-validated certificate for free (such as StartSSL or Let's Encrypt), but before being captured by the word free make sure to understand the various features of each certificate and buy/request the one from the authority that most fit your needs (and price).

Some elements that may affect your decision are: compatibility, supported validation types, lifetime of a certificate, covered names.